# If a BMS has a limit 40 A, it means that power supply should have maximum current less than 40 A or that power consumption should be less than 40 A?

Tags: current

For example, my battery pack can provide up to 40 A. Can I use BMS 15 A, if I know that the power consumption of my components is certainly less than 15 A? And if my power consumption is more than 15 A, for example 30 A on average, will the BMS burn?

Comment: When you say your battery pack can provide up to, are you referring to just the cell stack? Or does that include the BMS?

Comment: Without BMS. For example 4 pieces of 18650 and each can provide up to 10 A

Comment: And they are connected in a series (as a normal battery pack). BMS is 4S btw

Comment: If four 10 A cells are connected in series then the pack can supply 10 A, not 40 A. Series connection increases voltage but current remains the same. Parallel connection increases current but keeps voltage the same.

Comment: @Transistor thank you, I didn't notice my mistake. But the main question is still relevant

Comment: That's OK. I think you need to tidy up your question. For example, does the BMS have over-current protection? If not and you draw a current exceeding the specs then it's likely to fail.

Comment: If your cell stack can provide 40A but your BMS can only manage 15A that is acceptable. You just can't discharge greater than 15A. If that is acceptable for your application then go for it. When you say your power consumption is 15A, I assume you mean you are discharging 15A? If that is correct, you are fine, again your BMS is a 15A BMS. If you have a decent BMS it shouldn't let you discharge more than 15A else it damage itself.

Comment: @Transistor I checked - yes it has overcurrent protection. Also short circuit protection, overcharge/discharge detection and release.

Comment: @Tim51 thank you very much, I guess it answers my questions

Comment: No problem @pascalamin good luck with your BMS. Happy to help out anytime.

Comment: A 15A BMS will disconnect the battery when the current exceeds 15A. Note that a BMS can have different current ratings for charge and discharge : so it might allow charging at 10A and discharging at 20A for example.